# Why does a index seek becomes more expensive than an index scan

Tags: sql-server

I have a basic question about Index Scan/Seek. Index scan is effective when there are large number of rows to be fetched. That is index scan cost is inversely proportional to the number of rows returned. That is less the number of rows more expensive the query becomes as it has to scan all the pages which results in more IO.

I have searched the reason why seeks become more expensive than scans but I am not able to get the reason why seek becomes expensive.

What I am confused is with Index seek. Why index seek becomes expensive with more number of rows returned. Index seek will always be faster and efficient than scans as it directly touches the pages that contain the rows. So even with large number of rows returned index seek should always be efficent than Index scan. But this does not happen. I want to know exactly why at some point seek becomes expensive.

```
select id,name,col1,col2
from TableA   -- Will result in index scan. Table has 10000 rows with clustered index on ID column. Query has covering index.

select id,name,col1,col2
where ID between 1 and 10
from TableA   -- Optimizer Will use index Seek.
```

Now why does the below query becomes expensive when index seek is forced upon -

```
select id,name,col1,col2
from TableA with (forceseek)
```

Comment: may be [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/30/sql-server-index-seek-vs-index-scan-table-scan/) helps!!!

Comment: The qualification overhead of seek might be the cause

Comment: What is contained in the index? Just the ID? Is it a clustered index? If not then the key lookup required to get the other columns will be the reason for the performance hit.

Comment: Well, with an index seek, you find a particular value in your index quickly - and that's a good thing! But if you need to return more columns that those that make up the index, you need to do a **key lookup** for each value you found in the index - and the key lookup is a very expensive operation (basically going through the clustered index to find the data pages so you can return all columns needed). That's why at a certain point, it becomes "cheaper" to just do a scan (typically a "clustered index scan") than lots of seeks+key lookups

Comment: @marc_s : What if the query has covering index?. Will index seek for 10000 rows be efficent or index scan will be a better option. My query above has covering index. Id  has clustered index and name has non clustered index with included columns - col1,col2.

Comment: @sam: a covering index will help - since the expensive key lookup is not needed. But in the end, with a small number of rows, again it might just be "cheaper" for the query optimizer to just scan the index. The more rows your select extracts from the whole number of rows, the more likely is an index scan. The tipping point (when a seek is more efficient) is **surprisingly low** - often under 2-3% ! Anything more and a scan is more efficient

Comment: @marc_s : That' s exactly my question why Index seek has more overhead. What is the calculation. May be I am getting crazy with this thing. I know the reason for index scan but want to know the calculation of overhead in case of index seek. In one of the blogs of Pinal Dave it written that index seek is expensive because it has to read index and read pages also which is the cause of overhead. But this adds to my confusion that index scan also reads index and pages.?

Comment: An index scan **only** reads the **leaf level** of that particular index it's scanning - it does **NOT** look at the pages in the index navigation tree. Therefore, it might end up reading **fewer pages** than if you have to go through the index b-tree pages many many times. The SQL Server query optimizer is very smart that way and will pick the **fewest pages** to be read.

Comment: @marc_s : Got it.. Thanks. It's all making sense now..Thanks for your time and effort for this one. This is the exact answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why Clustered index Seek is expensive than Index scan is because Index seek starts reading the B tree right from Root nodes to Leaf nodes. This involves reading the index and pages inside the Leaf nodes. Hence results in more IO. So when selectivity is less optimizer chooses index scan instead of Index seek. Seek is better only when records returned are not more than 2 to 3%.